# How to implement nested query via Java code for mongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

```
db.a.find({ "id" : { "$in" : db.b.distinct("id") } })
```

This nested query is workable via shell client.

I'd like to implement it via Java code, but I don't know how.
Could anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

MongoCollection collectionA = database.getCollection("a");

MongoCollection collectionB = database.getCollection("b");

Bson filter1 = new Document("$in", collectionB.distinct("id"));

Bson filter2 = new Document("id",filter1);

List all = collectionA .find(filter2).into(new ArrayList ());

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, I will try this.